# How to use PostCSS in Vue.js?

Tags: css, webpack, vue.js, postcss

How can I handle PostCSS in Vue.js (webpack template)?

I searched it in many places but still can't find a good solution.

Please, give an example using the most used plugins, like cssnext, precss and sugarss.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `postcss-loader` with webpack

In your webpack.config

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: [
   ...,
  { loader: 'postcss-loader', options: { syntax: 'sugarss' } }
 ]
}
```